# How to show text area when check box is checked in android

Tags: android

Is there any way to show text-area when check-box is checked in android.
 Any help is greatly appreciated.

the below is my code

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2D Animation">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text area can be added to the layout XML and hidden until needed using:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Once the checkbox is checked, you can check the state and show the text area:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxID);
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
    textarea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

You can load all of this is an `onClickListener` so the action fires when the box is checked/unchecked.